# Flutter IOS flutter_web_auth_2 not building app

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I have been stuck on this for days I have been trying to use the flutter_web_auth_2 package for my app but it won't build every time I try I get this error

```
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'flutter_web_auth_2/flutter_web_auth_2-Swift.h' file not found
/Users/user/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_web_auth_2-2.1.0/ios/Classes/FlutterWebAuth2Plugin.m:1:8
```

I have an older project where I use the same package and it is working fine, but for this project something goes wrong. I have tried every solution that I have found on google and stackoverflow. For example

> 

Updated Xcode to latest
change the minimum iOS version to 12 from Xcode/Runner/General/Deployment Info
then, pod deintegrate, install, update, repo update
flutter clean
flutter pub get

> 

And also removed the launchscreen and main storyboard
I have the newest version of flutter, newest version of xcode and still it won't work.

I would be really glad if someone could have any new suggestions that I haven't tried

Comment: I have also tried to use different versions of the package but still it wont work

Comment: It is solved now, I deleted the Ios folder and copied a new one from a new flutter project